# "restaurant" has 1 or 2 morphemes?

Tags: morphology

Morpheme: The smallest unit of meaning that a word can be divided into The word ‘like’ contains one morpheme but ‘un-like-ly’ contains three.[Source](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/morpheme?q=morpheme)

The word "restaurant"  **/ˈres.tə.rɑːnt/** has 1 or 2 morphemes "res" & "taurant" ?

Why do I ask this question? 
It is because the voiceless aspirated and unaspirated stop consonants.

If `/st/` belongs to 1 morpheme the t will not be aspirated.

Ex: distaste /t/ will be be aspirated (dis & taste)

but distend /t/ won't be aspirated.

Comment: What do you think?

Comment: In my dialect of American English you'll hear both "res-trahnt" and "rest-uh-rahnt".

Comment: If it had two morphemes, it would be *restaur* + *ant* or *rest* + *ant*; *taurant* is ***not*** a morpheme (what would it mean? Do restaurants have anything to do with bulls?). And [etymologically](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=restaurant), it's *restore* + *ant*.

Comment: @Tom: the /t/ in *distaste* is definitely aspirated.

Comment: @PeterShor, thank you very much, I got a typo error.

Comment: There is no morpheme *res*, so there is no morphemic reason for the /t/ to be aspirated. Some English speakers might aspirate the /t/ anyway, though. It seems to me that the two-syllable pronunciation *restraunt* should have an aspirated /t/, since the second, accented, syllable begins with a /tr/, while the three-syllable pronunciation probably should not.

Comment: You're worrying about aspiration too much again. It is not phonemic in English, as we have previously explained to you. It varies between speakers and utterances, and is simply not noticed. You really must train yourself to stop noticing things native speakers do not.

Comment: @tchrist: aspiration is phonemic in English, but only at the start of words.

Comment: @PeterShor I realize that you're thinking of the blending of the traits of voicing and aspiration here, but I don't think this helps.

Comment: @tchrist: The middle consonants in *Whitestone* and *Hightstown*, despite both being /tst/, are phonemically different because the second /t/ is aspirated in Hightstown and unaspirated in Whitestone. A minimal pair might be *pit stop* and *Pitt's top*. These definitely sound different to me.

Comment: On the other hand, as @tchrist says, we won't notice whether or not you aspirate the /t/ in *restaurant*.

Comment: @PeterShor, Tom, the issue isn't really whether the /st/ is part of the same morpheme, it is whether they are in the same syllable or not. If they are in different morphemes they are almost definitely in different syllables and therefore there will be some aspiration - maybe appreciable, or maybe slight - for the /t/ which will be in the onset of the next syllable. If the /s/ is not part of a different morpheme, then it *might* be in the onset of the next syllable, in which case there will be no aspiration of the /t/.

Answer (score 1):

*Restaurant* has three morphemes: it is the participle (*–ant*) of a French verb, whose Latin ancestor added a prefix *re–* to the root *staur*; the Proto-Indo-European ancestor of this root is reconstructed as *steh₂u–ro–* (a suffixed variant of *steh₂*), so maybe I should say four morphemes, though I have no idea what the *–ro–* contributes to the meaning.

None of this helps you know whether the syllable break in English **pronunciation** is *re-stau* or *res-tau*.